# Mass rename JPG files using command line or perl?

Tags: perl, shell, unix

I have 519 JPG files in a folder that I need to massively rename.  In the file newnames.txt I have a list of the 519 new file names.  Is there a way through command line or perl to run through that list of names (each on a new line) and rename all the files?

Comment: have a look at the `rename` utility. If that doesn't help, then you need to update your question with how you do the mapping between newnames.txt and the actual file-names. The basic bash-loop looks like this: `while read nn; do echo $nn; done < newnames.txt` where you replace `echo` with your magic

Comment: Take a look at the `move` function in `File::Copy` module.

Comment: 1. what have you done so far?  2. what's the format of newnames.txt?

Comment: Seconded: how do you map filenames to "newnames.txt" data?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify how you map filenames to "newnames.txt" data, I will give a couple of solutions:

If the filenames are sorted alphabetically, and the order of newnames corresponds to that order:

```
use File::Slurp; 
use File::Copy qw/move/;
my @newnames=read_file("newnames.txt");
chomp(@newnames);
my @files = glob("*.JPG");
for (my $i=0; $i < @files; $i++) {
    die "Not enough new names for file $files[$i]" unless $newnames[$i];
    move($files[$i], $newnames[$i])
          or die "Failed to move $files[$i] to $newnames[$i] : $!";
}
```

If the filenames are in the same file as new names, in 2 columns:

```
use File::Slurp; 
use File::Copy qw/move/;
my @newnames=read_file("newnames.txt");
chomp(@newnames);
foreach my $line (@newnames) {
    my ($file, $new)= split(/,/, $line);
    move($file, $new)
          or die "Failed to move $file to $new : $!";
}
```